# Thesis project: Is it the last project required for a degree or a paper?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

If somebody is studying arts and he doesn't have to write a thesis but to complete a project as his last assignment before he can get his degree, can this project be called "thesis project", despite the fact that it is not a paper?

Comment: I can't think why you would call it a "thesis project" if you're not writing a thesis.  Surely, it's just a "project".

Comment: @Simon: You would call it that because that's what other people call it. (Although I don't know why they don't require a short paper to be turned in along with the project.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, many universities do use the term **thesis project** for non-written final projects like films, musical compositions, etc. required for the degree.  A **thesis project** may also include written documentation of process along with scholarly references and sometimes is defended before a committee in the same way a written thesis would be.

In **BFA** or an **MFA degree** programs (Bachelor's and Master's degrees in Fine Art) in the United States, there is definitely a widespread use of the term, **thesis project** to describe a creative project as the **capstone project** of the student's education at that degree level.

For example, here is a definition of a bachelor's level **thesis project**, which is not a written thesis of the traditional sort, provided by the School of Fine and Performing Arts at a major university in the United States.

> > > The phrase “**Thesis Project**” acknowledges the possibility of having **a scholarly honors endeavor which might not conform to the
> > >       narrow definition of a “thesis”**.
> >
> > The following are **examples of  previous Thesis Projects[at the University of Nebraska - Lincoln]:**
>
> 1) the arrangement of a particular symphony and a detailed description
>   of the process of composing arrangements with literary references
>
> 2) the creation of a portfolio of photographic works accompanied by a
>   lengthy historical and literary background
>
> 3) a complete set of costume designs with detailed information about
>   the design, research and garment building proces and photographs of
>   the realized costumes.
>
> **The project must have a significant written component, but it need not be in the format of a formal thesis**.
>
> https://bulletin.unl.edu/undergraduate/college/Fine+%26+Performing+Arts

Here's a **thesis exhibition** related to an MFA program at Rhode Island School of Design.  As you will see, there are only artworks on the walls.

> https://vimeo.com/66765330

Comment: Very informative answer that has improved my knowledge of terms constructed bt the legitimate conjunction of seemingly contradictory words!

Answer (score 1):

Thesis specifically refers to the written argument prepared and submitted in proper format after completing a theory-based study. Project, on the other hand, is often a more practice-based study, although you might submit a **project report** at its conclusion. I have never heard the term 'thesis project', probably because thesis and project are quite different in meaning. However, if this is a standard term used at your college/university then it is all right to use it for that specific purpose.

Comment: Please note that many terms used in the specialised languages of various fields like technology, law, computers or education need not necessarily be grammatically or even semantically sound from the point of view of general English. (Example: in India the first year of MA courses is called 'previous' and the second year is called 'final', which has always struck me as a minor nonsense ever since I did MA Sociology 15 years back.)Thus a project that replaces a thesis may well be called a 'thesis project' in certain colleges or universities!

Answer (score 0):

[Some schools](http://www.risd.edu/Policies/Academic/BFA_Degree_Requirements/) seem to call this a "degree project", which is probably a better name.

The name "thesis project" may lead people to expect that some written component (the *thesis*) was turned in, along with the project.

Answer (score 0):

A thesis refers to the written word so wouldn't be appropriate, and is usually 'about' the *project*, e.g.:

> Dissertations normally report on a research project or study, or an
>   extended analysis of a topic. The structure of the thesis or
>   dissertation explains the purpose, the previous research literature
>   which impinges on the topic of the study, the methods used and the
>   findings of the project.

([Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesis))

You could use:

**Final project**

E.g.: The term is used in *The Guardian* in this context:

> 'You spent how much on your final project?'

This is a term often applied to the type of project you mention.

In the specific arts context you refer if the work is being exhibited, you might refer to the work as:

The final show (from same source) :

> Can you put a price on creativity? For artists, balancing your great
>   vision for a project with how you'll actually afford to make it happen
>   is a continual struggle. And it's no different for students.
>
> An art student's final show is seen as a creative milestone – it's
>   your chance to be adventurous, to show what you can do and to start
>   making a name for yourself.

(The Guardian : *[You spent how much on your final project](http://www.theguardian.com/education/2014/may/23/graduate-art-final-show-costs)*)

([Wikipedia - Thesis](http://www.theguardian.com/education/2014/may/23/graduate-art-final-show-costs))